# send a number with sockets

Tags: java, readline

I tried to send an integer to the server. This is my client code

```
out = new PrintWriter(_socket.getOutputStream(), true); 
    Random rand = new Random();
    int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    out.println(n);
```

but how can the server read it ?

Comment: With his `Socket`'s `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DataOutputStream.writeInt() / DataInputStream.readInt() pair instead.